# Error en el concepto Eloquent y namespaces

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion con laravel 5.3

LA aplicacion la cambie el nombre App a MyApp con artisan

Todo me funciona bien excepto cuando he ido a usar un modelo eloquent, por ejemplo User

composer.json

```
...
"psr-4": {
            "Cprsync\\": "app/",
            "Abkrim\\Rbackcp\\": "vendor/abkrim/rbackcp/src/",
            "Abkrim\\Tools\\": "vendor/abkrim/tools/src/"
        }
...
```

app/Console/Commands/CpMyCommand.app

```
...
namespace Cprsync\Console\Commands;

// Some code
$cpanel = new Cpanel() // Llama a una Clase bajo namespace vendor/abkrim/rbackcp/src/; 
$cpanel->setUserList;
...
```

vendor/abkrim/rbackcp/src/Cpanel.php

```
<?php
namespace Abkrim\Rbackcp;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Log;
use SSH;
use Cprsync\User; // De acuerdo a https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-models

...
private $users;
...

...
public function setUserList()
    {
        // Some code update private $users
        $this->users = json_decode($this->getUserList(),true);

        $this->updateUsers();
    }

private function updateUSers()
{
    $users_cpanel = $this->users;

    $users = User:all(); // para coger todos los usuarios que existen en mi tabla de usuarios
    // Aqui se produce el error. 
 }
```

Error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
      Class 'Abkrim\Rbackcp\User' not found
```

Si devuelvo todo al estado de llamar a my app, de la forma original App (volviendo a ejecutar `php app:name App` si me funciona.

Cual es mi error ?

Comment: ¿Qué error aparece?

Comment: @Shaz lo pone... [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Class 'Abkrim\Rbackcp\User' not found

Answer (score 0):

Si dices que te da error al llamar un Model, debe ser que tienes algún namespace desactualizado. Por defecto al utilizar el comando se deberían actualizar los `namespace` de las clases dentro de la carpeta `app`, pero aseguraría que no de los `use` de cuando has importado modelos en otras clases para usarlos.

Aún así, estaría bien que nos mostraras el error que te da, seguro que contiene más información que ayude a solucionarlo.

Si trabajas en Sublime Text, puedes hacer por ejemplo `Ctrl + Mayus + F` para buscar una cadena de texto. Busca `App\User` en todo el directorio del proyecto tras haber cambiado el nombre a `MyApp`. Si encuentra coincidencias, seran de archivos que no se han actualizado y tendrás que cambiar esas coincidencias a `MyApp\User`. Ten en cuenta que esto puede pasar por cada modelo, aunque el User suele ser el más problemático al venir por defecte y tener referencias en varios sitios.

Answer (score 0):

De hecho estás llamando a la clase:

```
Abkrim\Rbackcp\User
```

cuando has declarado con:

```
use Cprsync\User;
```

Trata de llamarlo con:

```
$users = \Cprsync\User:all();
```

ó con lo que deseas:

```
$users = \Abkrim\Rbackcp\User::all();
```

Comment: Me parece que no. Primeo porque no llamo a la clase indicada, sino a use Cprsync\User; Ademas como digo, si cambio el nombre de mi App de Cprsync a App, funciona correctamente.

Comment: Que sospechoso, entonces fíjate en el archivo `App/config/entrust.php` si está todo bien con los namespace role y permission. Si no funciona prueba con otra versión (modificando en el composer.json) (quizá con una versión -dev)